# How to get your Google profile in the search results when searching your website

Tags: google-search

Check out this link:

http://www.google.com/#q=codinghorror.com

How come his profile is chowing up in the search results?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<a rel="author" href="https://profiles.google.com/<your profile>">
  <your name>
</a>
```

[Author information in search results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1408986)

Comment: Great work! Going to use this in my projects!